# How to fix GATTTools GLib-WARNING **: Invalid file descriptor

Tags: bluetooth

I'm trying to get the attributes of my bluetooth device (Bluetooth Smart LED Bulb) so that I can control it using Raspberry pi 3 model B, but I got this Invalid File descriptor.

`gatttool -b 00:E0:4C:EF:9D:52 -I
 [00:E0:4C:EF:9D:52][LE]> connect
 Attempting to connect to 00:E0:4C:EF:9D:52
 Connection successful
 [00:E0:4C:EF:9D:52][LE]>
 (gatttool:4006): GLib-WARNING **: Invalid file descriptor.`

`[00:E0:4C:EF:9D:52][LE]> primary
 Command Failed: Disconnected
 [00:E0:4C:EF:9D:52][LE]>`

Answer (score 2):

When the bluetooth device disconnects (due to range, signal strength etc) the underlying cleanup process doesn't get invoked properly - hence the invalid descriptor. See this article for more info: http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-bluetooth/msg63249.html

Simply put the tool doesn't handle unsolicited/unexpected disconnections very well.

Try moving your PI and bulb close to each other, connect with gatttool and then moving further apart - you'll see what I mean.